# rsync copy with partial recovery, but don't copy if it already exists

Tags: rsync

I am trying to use `rsync` to sync directories between two servers, but if the file exists, it should not attempt to move it again.  I wanted to be able to recover the operation if I cancel command or the connection breaks, by executing the command again.

However what's happening with only -P is that it would still attempt to move files that already exist on the target.

I tried the --size-only option, but it's not picking up where it left off.

Ideally it should be driven by the modification date, so that it will move if the target date is not up to date, and still be able to pickup where it left off.

This is what I had been working on (works okay but not exactly). Hoping for some suggestions on a better solution.

```
rsync -azP --size-only --info=progress2 --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --exclude "jb-*/names" jb-* user1@site.org:/target
```

Ideally:

- copy file if file does not exist or is out of date or size doesn't match; otherwise, don't copy if it already exists.
- pick up copying file if the operation was terminated
- preserve directory structure

Comment: What types are the source and destination file systems? Usually with the `-a` flag `rsync` won't recopy an unchanged file

Comment: Removing the `--size-only` makes `rsync` do what you want when I try it here. Therefore there's something else in the equation

Comment: @roaima basically, two linux file systems (ubuntu). I my case, it was recopying over and over again.

Comment: On the remote site please double check you have permissions to write to the directories `rsync` has created underneath `/target`